# is it safe and common to use CSS3 Flexible Box Layout these days?

Tags: css, flexbox

It's been a long time since CSS3 came up and the flex box layout, but i do not see it being used as commonly as other layout methods like floats. I personally have never used flex box for layout so i was wondering if i should start using it and what is the future of flex box as a layout option.

Comment: [caniuse.com/flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Comment: Yes i see that all current major browsers support it, but why is it not being used as common as other methods?

Comment: I'd guess because of the lack of IE9/IE10 support.  A good number of people still use those browsers for now.